# Creating Resource file in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the beolw code to create a resource file in C#.

```
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(@"C:\ABC\Try1.resources");
writer.AddResource(Name, Value);
writer.Close();
```

BUt when I am trying to open the resource file which is being created, its seems to be distorted. Normally when I double clickon any resources file (.resx) it opens in an xml format.

Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

`ResourceWriter` writes files in binary format. To write it in xml format use [ResXResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)